# Select groups based off of single row value within group?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm working with payroll data, and I want to pull only checks that have overtime on them. A check with overtime on it will have a row showing payroll code '5'. I know I can filter and bring back the rows that have '5' in them, but I need all rows from the qualifying check, not just the row with the '5' in it.

Here is an basic example of the data:

```
ROW  CHKNUM  PAYCODE  AMOUNT
1    000010     1        $15
2    000010     1N       $20
3    000010     5        $25
4    000011     1        $15
5    000011     1N       $20
6    000012     1        $15
7    000012     5        $25
8    000013     1        $15
9    000014     1        $15
10   000014     5N       $30
```

I need to return all rows for check number 10, 12, and 14, because that check number contains '5' pay code. (also need all pay codes leading in 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be even simpler:

```
select * from Table1 where "CHKNUM" in(select "CHKNUM" from Table1 where 
regexp_like("PAYCODE",'(.)*5(.)*'));
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6acf0/4

for tsql its like:

```
select * from Table1 where "CHKNUM" in(select "CHKNUM" from Table1 
where PATINDEX ('(.)*5(.)*',"PAYCODE")=0);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66036/3

use this:

```
 select * from Table1 where "CHKNUM" in(select "CHKNUM" from Table1 
 where "PAYCODE" like '5%');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66036/5

Comment: Will this normally reduce performance significantly? I tried both of the above and end up waiting a very long time to it to execute.
Actually I just double checked a specific check number, and it doesn't include any pay codes of '5%'

Comment: The last one didn't increase performance at all, but I changed my data source to the table instead of the view i created and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.chknum = t.chknum and t1.paycode like '5%');
```

Comment: What does the 'select 1' do?

Comment: @Christian Love  It fulfills the requirement that the SELECT statement select something.  In the case of EXISTS sub-selects no data is actually returned to the outer SELECT it instead either resolves to True or False.

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient:

```
SELECT * FROM #Payroll
WHERE CHKNUM in (select CHKNUM from #Payroll where PAYCODE like '5%')
```